# Require fails with floating point numbers

Tags: java, floating-point, kotlin

```
private void waveformProgress(double currentProgressPercentage) {
   if (currentProgressPercentage < 0.0f) currentProgressPercentage = 0.0f;
   if (currentProgressPercentage > 1.0f) currentProgressPercentage = 1.0f;
   waveView.setProgress((float) (100.0 * currentProgressPercentage));
   ..
 }
```

I have rare crash reports on the setProgress line, in the call to a kotlin setter:

```
var progress: Float = 0F
        set(value) {
            require(value in 0..100) { "Progress must be in 0..100" }
...
        }
```

I know about floating point equality and all, but how is it possible that the require fails here? How would I correct it? I suppose it's possible Crashlytics is reporting new version number when the crash happened in old version that didn't ensure the number was between 1..100.

Comment: Can you construct a [test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Since value is `Float` you need to use range constructed from floats to be precise: `value in 0F..100F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `currentProgressPercentage` for which you should get this exception: [`NaN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (it isn't actually a single value, but this doesn't matter here). Both comparisons will be false, and `(float) (100.0 * currentProgressPercentage)` will return a `NaN` which isn't in range `0..100`. A `NaN` can be produced, e.g., by calculating `0.0/0.0`.